# NestJS Logging :: Enabling/disabling globally

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a couple of utility classes that are called by the Controllers or Services in NestJS. Each utility class is declared with a logger, like so:

```
export class A {
  
  private logger = new Logger(A.name);

  test() {
    this.logger.log('TEST');
  }

}
```

This helps during development and while troubleshooting, but in production, I'd like to be able to turn the logs off for `debug`, `verbose`, and `log` levels.

I haven't been able to figure out a reliable way to do that globally, apart from commenting out the logging statements individually. Is there a way to do so from a central place like `main.ts`?

Comment: Make the Logger constructor return a singleton and the all references to the logger are the same logger. Then expose methods on the logger to change the log level etc.

Comment: Thank @Joe. The logger is a built-in class in the `NestJS` framework. And I'd like to keep separate instances of the logger for each class (so that it can also log the class names as well when called from within).

Comment: Each instance could pull config in from a shared file/instance that governs log settings. Same idea if you still want independent logger instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary in your app's `main.ts` file to set the log levels when you create your `app`:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? ['log', 'debug', 'error', 'verbose', 'warn'] : ['error', 'warn'],
})
```